# Do i have to convert a list of list of strings to a 2d array in this case?

Tags: android, api, list, multidimensional-array

I am developing an app for **Android** and i am using **ExpandableListActivity**.

I am extracting data from sqlite db which is in this format:

```
Id | Category | Name
```

**CODE**
here is the code that grabs the data:

```
List<String> groups = new ArrayList<String>();
List<String> books = new ArrayList<String>();
List<String> elecs = new ArrayList<String>();
List<List<String>> children = new ArrayList<List<String>>();

 Cursor c = mDbHelper.fetchAllItems();

        startManagingCursor(c);

        // for all rows
        for(int i=0; i<c.getCount(); i++)
        {
            c.moveToNext();
            String t = c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("category"));

            switch (getCat(t))
            {
            case Books:
                books.add(c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("name")));
                Log.d("FROM: ", c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("name")));
                if(!(groups.contains("Books"))) groups.add("Books");

                break;
            case Electronics:

                elecs.add(c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("name")));               
                Log.d("FROM: ", c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("name")));
                if(!(groups.contains("Electronics"))) groups.add("Electronics");

                break;
            default:
                break;
            }   // end switch
        } // end for loop

        children.add(books);
        children.add(elecs);
```

**OUTPUT**
when i run this app here is how the screen looks like:

```
Books
Electronics
```

and when i click on Books or Electronics it shows everything. Like this:

```
Books
 [c programming, perl]
 [cd, laptop, psp]
Electronics
 [c programming, perl]
 [cd, laptop, psp]
```

**ISSUE**
i think the issue is coming from this method (getChild):

```
public class MyExpandableListAdapter extends BaseExpandableListAdapter {

        List<String> GRP;
        List<List<String>> CHLD;

        public MyExpandableListAdapter(List<String> grps, List<List<String>> chldrn) {
            GRP = grps;
            CHLD = chldrn;
        }
...
...
public Object getChild(int groupPosition, int childPosition) {
    // CHLD[groupPosition][childPosition]; ORIGINAL, where CHLD was a 2d array
     return CHLD.get(childPosition);   MODIFIED
}
```

do i have to convert my list of list of strings to a 2d array?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I cannot see how and where you use your ominous `getChild()`, and I don't know what `CHLD` is, as well as what the 'orginal' was used because a starting [XXX][XXX] is not a valid java syntax. Also Are you shure that the list of electronics is the same than the List of Books? It might be a hint that your data parsing is wrong, or the db contains invalid data.

But what might help you, is the following:

- in your first sample `children.get(i)` will return a `List<String>`
- I assume that there was a reason for `groupPosition` and `childPosition` inside your `getChild()` method. But your current implementation ignores the `groupPosition` totally.

Cannot help you further without knowing what exactly the issue is.

***ADD according to your new Edit:***

your `CHLD` is a List of List of Strings. correct implementation will be as following:

```
public class MyExpandableListAdapter extends BaseExpandableListAdapter {

        List<String> GRP;
        List<List<String>> CHLD;

        public MyExpandableListAdapter(List<String> grps, List<List<String>> chldrn) {
            GRP = grps;
            CHLD = chldrn;
        }

    public Object getChild(int groupPosition, int childPosition) {
         return CHLD.get(groupPosition).get(childPosition);
    }
}
```

Comment: you hit it on the head :). Thank you very much!